# Нет подключения клиента к серверу

Tags: c#, c++, клиент-сервер

Есть клиент на C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#pragma comment ( lib, "ws2_32.lib" )

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 WSADATA wsaData;
 SOCKET clientSocket;
 SOCKADDR_IN clientSocketAddress;
 DWORD dwError;

 WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);

 clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 clientSocketAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
 clientSocketAddress.sin_port = htons(7777);
 clientSocketAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.76");

 connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientSocketAddress, sizeof (clientSocketAddress));
 closesocket(clientSocket);

 return 0;;
}
```

Есть сервер на C#:

```
private void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.76");
                IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0];
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 7777);
                Socket listenSocket = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                listenSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                listenSocket.Listen(10000);

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listenSocket.Accept();
                    // Прием клиентов
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Клиент не подключается к серверу.

Как установить связь между клиентом и сервером?

**Обновление**:

```
private void StartServer()
        {
                IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7777);
                Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                listenSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                listenSocket.Listen(10000);           

            }
        }
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы ответить на Ваш вопрос, надо поставить Visual Studio, сделать проект на C#, вставив туда Ваш код, и потанцевав с бубном, потому что этого, конечно же, будет мало. Затем сделать проект на C++, куда опять же вставить приведенный код, и, потанцевав с настройками и дописками, получить два проекта. И потом начать тестировать, чтобы в отладке что-то увидеть. Ценность Вашего вопроса - почти нулевая, т.к. не ясно, кому это еще понадобится в таком виде. Учитывая ценность вопроса и тот факт, сколько нужно действий, неужели Вы думаете, найдется много желающих Вам помочь?

Comment: Подумайте, как сделать Ваш вопрос интересным другим людям (что повысит качество ресурса хэшкод), и как при этом упростить возможную помощь Вам?

Comment: @updat, начните с простого (например, для раздельного тестирования компонент используйте ncat (для винды он тоже есть)).

1. Этот Ваш клиент подключается к ncat?

2. ncat соединяется с этим Вашим сервером?

Вот если на оба вопоса ответ -- ДА, тогда надо подумать...

Comment: Не понимаю: как может быть использован любой из имеющихся IP адресов ? Это же противоречит самому определению endpoint'а - "конечная точка = конкретный IP + порт"